# Calling service for factory in controller

Tags: angularjs, factory

I have a problem when calling a service created using .factory in my controller.
The code looks like the following.
Factory (app.js):

```
.factory('Database',function($http){

    return {

      getDatabase: function(){

        var database = {};

        $http.get('http://localhost:3001/lookup').
          success(function(data){

            database.companyInfo = data.info.companyInfo;
            });


          }).
          error(function(data){
            console.log('Error' + data);
          });

        return database;

      }
    };
  })
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('webClientApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function (Database,Features,$scope,$http) {




        $scope.databaseString = [];
        $scope.quarters = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'];
        $scope.years = ['2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010',
      '2011','2012','2013','2014'];
        $scope.features = Features.getFeatures();
        $scope.database = Database.getDatabase();

        console.log($scope.database);
```

Now when I inspect the element in Firebug I get the `console.log($scope.database)` printed out before the GET statement result. `$scope.database` is shown as an `Object {}` with all the proprieties in place.
However if I try to use `console.log($scope.database.companyInfo)` I get an `undefined` as result, while instead I should get that `data.info.companyInfo' that I passed from the`Database` service (in this case an array).

What is the problem here? Can someone help me?
(If you need clarifications please let me know..)

Comment: `$http.get` is **asynch**. That's why when `console.log($scope.database)` printed out before the GET statement result

Comment: That's what I though as well. Thank you! However, is there a way to get around the asynchrony of $http.get. Like $document.ready()?

Comment: you could either pass in a callback or return a promise from the function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The $http.get() call is asynchronous and makes use of promise objects.  So, based on the code you provided it seems most likely that you are outputting the $scope.database before the success method is run in the service.

I build all my service methods to pass in a success or failure function.  This would be the service:

```
.factory('Database',function($http){

return {

  getDatabase: function(onSuccuess,onFailure){

    var database = {};

    $http.get('http://localhost:3001/lookup').
      success(onSuccess).
      error(onFailure);

  }
 };
})
```

This would be the controller code:

```
angular.module('webClientApp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function (Database,Features,$scope,$http) {


$scope.databaseString = [];
$scope.quarters = ['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'];
$scope.years = ['2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010',
      '2011','2012','2013','2014'];
$scope.features = Features.getFeatures();
Database.getDatabase(successFunction,failureFunction);

successFunction = function(data){
    $scope.database = data.info.companyInfo;
    console.log($scope.database);
});

failureFunction = function(data){
     console.log('Error' + data);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your code in the following way:

```
.factory('Database',function($http){
  return {
     getDatabase: function(){
        return $http.get('http://localhost:3001/lookup');
     }
  };
})
```

Then get the response in controller(Promise chain)

```
Database.getDatabase()
   .then(function(data){
      //assign value
   })
   .catch(function(){
   })
```